# How to browserify my ES6 tests without rebundling my app

Tags: typescript, jasmine, ecmascript-6, browserify

I'm developing react application with ES6 syntax, modules and imports.

I compile my app using following commands:

```
browserify components/app.tsx -x react -x react-dom -p tsify -o > scripts/bundle.js
```

Now I would like to compile all my tests into separate file:

```
browserify tests/tests.tsx -p tsify -o > scripts/tests.js
```

however, this includes all the actual app code in tests.js since I imported them in my test files.

how can I avoid rebundling the actual app code into tests.js?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I've end up with:

```
browserify components/app.tsx tests/tests.ts -p [factor-bundle -o scripts/app.js -o tests/scripts/tests.js] -x react -x react-dom -p tsify -o scripts/bundle.js
```

factor-bundle plugin creates two files (app.js and tests.js) which reference common file "bundle.js";